# A/V in delphi application when it is starting

Tags: exception

I have an old delphi application.

If i start it outside of ide, runtime error 216 occurs quickly before mainform is shown.
If i start it inside ide, after a few seconds, ide says "too many consecutive exceptions".

I set breakpoints on first lines of initialization sections of all my units. And also add breakpoints of my units' finalization sections. Debugger does not stop on any of them.

When I remove first two units FastMM, FastMM4Messages, it runs inside or outside ide (I know it is not about FastMM4 and FastMM4 is okay).

I set breakpoint at ntdll.KiUserExceptionDispatcher in assembly pane. Now it stops at this breakpoints before any of my units' initialization and finalization.

Any advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found "FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll" was damaged partially (without change on file modified date or file size). After replaced it with good copy, my problem was solved.